# SQL query to retrieve a row with the highest possible ID

Tags: sql, max

I have the following data:

```
ID  Value
1   X
2   Y
3   Y
4   X
5   X
6   Y
```

How to retrieve the row where Value = "X" and ID is the highest possible? (in that case it would be the 5th row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, Value
FROM table
WHERE Value = 'X'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Or another way (this works as you already know the value you want):

```
SELECT MAX(ID), 'X' AS Value
FROM table
WHERE Valud = 'X'
```

Comment: I didn't refresh the page before commenting so I didn't see the new method. The first one with max(id) works without problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
     Value
    ,MAX(ID) HighestID
FROM
    table
WHERE
    Value = 'X'
GROUP BY
    Value
```

Comment: Plus 10 because aggregate functions should be much quicker than "top" queries. Also, "top" is not consistent between vendors...

Comment: I'm upvoting this for the same reason as mentioned by Neville K.

Answer (score 1):

Select Top 1 * from tableName where value = 'X' order by ID Desc